# Get MVC3 to use Oracle for user roles and memberships

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, membership-provider, odp.net

I'm having problems getting my MVC3 front end to use an Oracle 11g database to hold the user memberships.

I've been following this [simple tutorial](http://quysnhat.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/using-membership-with-oracle-database-in-asp-net-mvc-3/)  but can't get it to work.

Some things I've done so far:

- Downloaded and installed the Oracle Data Provider for .NET (ODAC 11.2
  Release 4 (11.2.0.3.0) )
- Run the InstallAllOracleASPNETProviders.sql against the database on
  the development server.
- Tested the connection via SQL developer (using the TNSNames file)
  with no issues.
- Unable to create a connection to the database under the Server
  Explorer pane is Visual Studio 2010 which seems related.

Having checked the database I can see that the "ORA_ASPNET_" tables have been created OK.

I'd appreciate a steer on where I'm going wrong as this **SHOULD** be easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appeared to be related to the connection string.

I had been using the TNS names file for the connection details but this wasn't being picked up.

I modified the connection string to include the server, port and service name as follows:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="OraAspNetConnectionString" 
      connectionString="Data Source=svr56:1521/TCO1103;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Ora_Asp;Password=*****;" 
      providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client="/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

The problem creating the connection is the Server Explorer also resolved itself once I used the same details in the Data source name box.

> svr56:1521/TCO1103;Persist Security Info=True;User
>   ID=Ora_Asp;Password=*****;
>   [image]